# set php $_SESSION variable in AJAX

Tags: ajax

sorry for question, there are examples but I can not get it. My code does not work. My test.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="doTheFunction();">Run the script</button>
<script>
function doTheFunction(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","set.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php echo $_SESSION['w'];?> /*after button onclick and page refresh session 
shoud be set*/
</body>
</html>
```

My set.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['w'] = 'abc';
?>
```

Session was not set :/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION can only be accessed from a running PHP-script and not a JavaScript onClick-event. So you can not change the values in $_SESSION without doing a GET or POST  to a PHP script.

If you want you could do a AJAX call and run a script that updates the values in $_SESSION. In JavaScript you can use *document.cookie* to change the value of the cookie.

Comment: thanks a lot. Cookie works, session does not

Comment: <button onclick="doTheFunction();">Run the script</button>

Comment: I`m blind!!! Thank you!!!